# Should I use private fields in my C# class or public Properties are good enough?

Tags: c#, oop

as my question said I'm confused in case where should I use private fields or not..

Here is my `Person` class for example:

I know it's useful to use private fields when I want to get `FullName` quickly..
Actually **that's only example** where I'm adding addition code in some of my getters,
so I would like to avoid private fields, so I might start using public properties because anyway in the background private field will be created?

```
 private string _firstName;
 private string _lastName;

 public string FullName
 {
    get { return _firstName + _lastName; }
 }
```

Anyway, could I do something like this, remove private fields - > add only public properties ? I guess there is no issue about this code below.. ?

```
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName  { get; set; }

 public string FullName
 {
   get { return FirstName + LastName; }
 }
```

Should I prefer example 2? I mean is there any problems if I stay with example 2? Because I want my classes to look cleaner without private fields :)

Comment: In this particular case, it depends on how FirstName and LastName are assigned. If they too are being assignable publicly then making them public property makes sense. If they are only assigned via constructor or some other method then they can be private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here will really depend on whether you *want* the first/last name to be on the public API. If you do: 2 is ideal for your typing convenience. At runtime, thanks to JIT magic, 1 and 2 will be largely indistinguishable (except for the accessibility concern), so you might as well go with the most convenient and expressive form, which is usually: 2.

Even 1 could use private automatically implemented properties *if you so wish*, although it is pretty rare to see that in reality - most code either uses public properties or private fields, depending on the intent; public fields are anecdotally rare, as are private properties.

It *might* also make sense to have the first and last names public but read-only, i.e.

```
public string FirstName { get; }
public string LastName  { get; }

public string FullName => FirstName + LastName;
```

or public but only writable inside the type:

```
public string FirstName { get; private set; }
public string LastName  { get; private set; }

public string FullName => FirstName + LastName;
```